# Automate "atlasvpn connect"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I want to connect to a server through *AtlasVPN* automatically. But I have some difficulties to create a code that works at the startup of my *Ubuntu* system. Look at how that company's script works and try to assist me. I sent e-mails to the VPN's support, but they provided me generic informations, sadly.

Terminal log:

```
@user: $ atlasvpn connect
    1 - Standard
    2 - Streaming
    3 - SafeSwap
    4 - MultiHop
    Enter a number corresponding to the desired category: 1
    1 - Netherlands - Amsterdam
    2 - United States - New York
    3 - Hong Kong - Hong Kong
    4 - United States - Dallas
    5 - United States - Los Angeles
    6 - Singapore - Singapore
    7 - Finland - Helsinki
    8 - Norway - Oslo
    9 - New Zealand - Auckland
    10 - Argentina - Buenos Aires
    Enter a number corresponding to the desired server: 10
    You have successfully connected to Argentina - Buenos Aires.
@user:
```

- I hope you realized all the VPN's script is one command-line and that
  is why I can't make my own code for that activity.
- The **"Enter a number corresponding to the desired category: "** and **"Enter a number corresponding to the desired server: "** are in the same command-line, then I need script that choose both of my desired options  in the same line.

Look at my screenshots to understand it better:

[image: AtlasVPN modus operandi - part 1]

[image: AtlasVPN modus operandi - part 2]

This type of script does not work with AtlasVPN's command-line software:

```
#!/bin/bash
atlasvpn connect
1
10
```

How can I automate connecting with `atlasvpn connect`?

Comment: Welcome, try something like this: `(echo 1; echo 10) | atlasvpn connect`.

Comment: We understand  the need, probably the `expect` automator is a good step.

Answer (score 0):

If the script doesn't accept `stdin` via `(echo 1; echo 10) | atlasvpn connect` you can try automating it with an [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script

`~/bin/autoatlas`:

```
#/bin/env expect

spawn atlasvpn connect
expect {
    "*Enter a number corresponding to the desired category:*" {
        send "1\r"
        expect {
            "*Enter a number corresponding to the desired server:*" {
                send "10\r"
                interact
            }
        }
    }
```